# Comparing sub-lists of a list

Tags: prolog

Hello I am new to Prolong in particular lists. I need to be able to compare the heads and tails of subsists against other subsists from the same list.

For example I if given a list `[[1, 2], [2,3], [3,1]]` I need to identify if there is a loop of numbers. How would I access the information in these subsists and see if they are of the form `[[x|y][y|z][z|x]]` ?

Currently I am using a `[H|T]` operations to separate the original list into
H=`[1,2]` and T=`[[2,3],[3,1]]` but my problem now is finding a way to further break up `H` so that I can access the 1 and 2 stored in it.

Currently I am truing the following

```
Connection([],1).
Connection([H|T],COUNT) :-
    Loop(H, T), 
    where COUNT is COUNT +1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In Prolog `[H|T]` is an arbitrarily long list where `T` (itself a list) is the tail. If your elements are all 2-element lists, they can be represented more easily with `[X,Y]` (don't use `[X|Y]` as you show, which is incorrect). Now your overall list is arbitrarily long, so it is, as you show, suitably represented as `[H|T]`. But you can also check the first two elements: `[H1, H2|T]` or even write `[[X1,Y1], [X2, Y2]|T]`, etc.

Comment: Predicates cannot begin with a capital letter, so `Connection([], 1)` is a syntax error. Use `connection`. Also, I suppose an empty list really has a 0-length loop, so don't you want `connection([], 0).`?